# Listview items not scrolling up when keyboard apprear

Tags: android, listview, scroll, keyboard

I have listview that contain 20 rows,

```
item--1
item--2
.
.
item--19
item--20
```

This are scrollable

---

list last items

item--17 clicked
keyboad shown up its covering editexs 
now `item--15` showing

```
item--15
EDITTEXT
KEYBOARB
```

this scrolling upto item--15
I applied SOFT INPUT ADJUST PAN

then now 
showing `item--17` layout moves up

```
item--16
item--17
KEYBOARD
```

now scrolling upto item--17 
But my problem is

item -- 17 after I have next item--18 and item--19 and item -- 20

When keyboard appears item-17 thats shows only scrolls.

next items are not showing.
How to scroll last items.

> activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list_item"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post xml code...

Comment: use android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

Comment: wow working but edittext cursor focus losing... how to focus maintaining in edittext

Comment: add focusable =true and focusableintouchmode=true in edittext

Comment: not woking, focus losing, re-click then gain focus @DivyeshPatel

Comment: then remove stateHidden from softinputmode

Comment: Not working same problem@DivyeshPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` in `AndroidMainfest.xml` or add this in class file `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_PAN);`

Answer (score 1):

you cae Use RecycleView instead of Listview

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/

Answer (score -1):

in your manifest activity tag put  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"` property see below example

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize">
```